# How to determine router's management ip?

Tags: networking, router

I have a spectrum cable modem/router.. after a bit of fishing I found online the management ip: 192.168.100.1

The gateway has a different ip.

If I didn't get lucky with a google search on possible management ip's how could I determine the management ip?  (Nmap the lan and look for http/s?).

Only info I really saw on wireshark was just gateway info.. not sure if in this case you would need to know the management ip beforehand.  And if you don't know the ip you would then have to do a hard reset.

What I'm curious about.. if there a way to determine the management ip from the gateway ip?  I was thinking maybe nmap everyting on the lan and start probing..

ipconfig

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : socal.rr.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-76-1C-27-B1-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 104.32.211.XXX(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.224.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, August 4, 2019 10:14:23 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, August 5, 2019 9:08:44 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 104.32.192.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 142.254.237.61
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 209.18.47.63
                                       209.18.47.61
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your router's model? Your numbers are really strange, the spectrum gateway is usually `192.168.1.1`. Try maybe to factory reset the router (careful : some settings may be lost).

Comment: technicolor-tc8715d, found a bunch of poss spectrum management ip's and ran thru them till I found one that would work.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://d15yx0mnc9teae.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/technicolor-tc8715d-userguide.pdf), page 25, the Admin Tool is found at `http://192.168.0.1`. Your router is set up weirdly.

Comment: Agreed! Yea spectrum did some remote management to enable the modem after we moved.. started going down the rabbit hole after that lol

Comment: So demand them to give you a real professional to undo the damage the first one did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just nmap the entire lan range (which would normally be a /24) and won't take you too long, but there's no guarantee that it even has the management IP configured within the same lan range that it's been accessed in.

Basically, if you don't know what the IP is set to, and you can't find it via some simple means such as nmap, then your only option is to reset it back to manufacturing defaults.

Comment: Thanks! Yea this is was I was worried about.. I got lucky but wasn't sure if there was another way heh